# How to validate and exclude data at ingestion time for Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am sending data from web client to event hub and then ingest into Azure Data Explorer.
The event generated by web client has a `timestamp` field, and when event hub receives the event, it will add a `EventEnqueuedUtcTime` field. Both are UTC timestamp.

Is there a way to compare the the two timestamps at Data Explorer ingestion, and exclude the data if the time difference is more than a certain vaule?

for example, if `EventEnqueuedUtcTime - timestamp > x minutes`, then we don't ingest this event into Data Explorer?

Comment: just take a look into ago() `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/agofunction`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with [Update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy). The update policy can have a condition like this:

```
T
| where  EventEnqueuedUtcTime - timestamp < x minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

you can implement that kind of filtering logic as part of an update policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

1. ingest your raw data into `SourceTable`.
2. create `TargetTable`, which has the exact same schema as `SourceTable`.
3. set the update policy on `TargetTable` to have `SourceTable` as its source table, and define the filtering logic as part of the `Query` property of the policy (you can use a stored function here too)
4. configure `SourceTable` to have a "zero" (`00:00:00`) soft delete period as part of its retention policy, so that the raw data is never made queryable and isn't retained.

Answer (score 0):

Example how ingestion time works!

Let’s say you have event table with field
.create table events (source: string)

And orders table with fields
.create table orders (source: string, LastModifiedDate: datetime)

Now you are copying events table source to orders table but, you want to generate your last modified date on orders table as ingestion time.

Steps:

1. Create events table - .create table events (source: string)
2. Create orders table - .create table orders (source: string,    LastModifiedDate: datetime)
3. Create function to extend lastmodified in events table
   .create function eventRecordsExpand() { events | extends LastModifiedDate = ingestiontime()}
4. Alter your orders table to update policy
   .alter table orders policy update @‘[{“source”: “events”, “query”: “eventRecordsExpand()“, “isEnabled”: “True”}]’

This will ingest records from events table to orders table with LastModifiedDate from orders table as ingestion time.